# Problems with Smoothing graphs in Python

Tags: python, graph, smoothing

I have been trying to smooth a plot which is noisy due to the sampling rate I'm using, and what it's counting. I've been using the help on here - mainly [Plot smooth line with PyPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283649/plot-smooth-line-with-pyplot) (although I couldn't find the "spline" function and so am using `UnivarinteSpline` instead)

However, whatever I do I keep getting errors with either the pyplot error that `"x and y are not of the same length"` or, that the `scipi.UnivariateSpline` has a value for `w` that is incorrect. I am not sure quite how to fix this (not really a Python person!) I've attached the code although it's just the plotting bit at the end that is causing problems. Thanks

```
import os.path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate as sci
import numpy as np
def main():
    jcc = "0050"
    dj = "005"
    l = "060"
    D = 20
    hT = 4 * D
    wT1 = 2 * D
    wT2 = 5 * D
    for jcm in ["025","030","035","040","045","050","055","060"]:
        characteristic = "LeadersOnly/Jcm" + jcm + "/Jcc" + jcc + "/dJ" + dj + "/lambda" + l + "/Seed000"
        fingertime1 = []
        fingertime2 = []
        stamp =[]
        finger=[]
        for x in range(0,2500,50):
            if x<10000:
                z=("00"+str(x))
            if x<1000:
                z=("000"+str(x))
            if x<100:
                z=("0000"+str(x))
            if x<10:
                z=("00000"+str(x))
            stamp.append(x)
            path = "LeadersOnly/Jcm" + jcm + "/Jcc" + jcc + "/dJ" + dj + "/lambda" + l + "/Seed000/profile_" + str(z) + ".txt"
            if os.path.exists(path):
                f = open(path, 'r')
                pr1,pr2=np.genfromtxt(path, delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
                p1=[]
                p2=[]
                h1=[]
                h2=[]
                a1=[]
                a2=[]
                finger1 = 0
                finger2 = 0
                for b in range(len(pr1)):
                    p1.append(pr1[b])
                    p2.append(pr2[b])
                for elem in range(len(pr1)-80):
                    h1.append((p1[elem + (2*D)]-0.5*(p1[elem]+p1[elem + (4*D)])))
                    h2.append((p2[elem + (2*D)]-0.5*(p2[elem]+p2[elem + (4*D)])))
                    if h1[elem] >= hT:
                        a1.append(1)
                    else:
                        a1.append(0)
                    if h2[elem]>=hT:        
                        a2.append(1)
                    else:
                        a2.append(0)
                for elem in range(len(a1)-1):
                    if (a1[elem] - a1[elem + 1]) != 0:
                        finger1 = finger1 + 1
                finger1 = finger1 / 2
                for elem in range(len(a2)-1):
                    if (a2[elem] - a2[elem + 1]) != 0:
                        finger2 = finger2 + 1
                finger2 = finger2 / 2
                fingertime1.append(finger1)
                fingertime2.append(finger2)
                finger.append((finger1+finger2)/2)
        namegraph = jcm
        stampnew = np.linspace(stamp[0],stamp[-1],300)
        fingernew = sci.UnivariateSpline(stamp, finger, stampnew)
        plt.plot(stampnew,fingernew,label=namegraph)
    plt.show()      

main()
```

For information, the data input files are simply a list of integers (two lists seperated by tabs, as the code suggests).

Here is one of the error codes that I get:

```
0-th dimension must be fixed to 50 but got 300

error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)

/group/data/Cara/JCMMOTFingers/fingercount_jcm_smooth.py in <module>()
    116
    117 if __name__ == '__main__':
--> 118     main()
    119
    120

/group/data/Cara/JCMMOTFingers/fingercount_jcm_smooth.py in main()
     93                 #print(len(stamp))
     94                 stampnew = np.linspace(stamp[0],stamp[-1],300)
---> 95                 fingernew = sci.UnivariateSpline(stamp, finger, stampnew)
     96                 #print(len(stampnew))
     97                 #print(len(fingernew))

/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/fitpack2.pyc in __init__(self, x, y, w, bbox, k, s)
     86         #_data == x,y,w,xb,xe,k,s,n,t,c,fp,fpint,nrdata,ier
     87         data = dfitpack.fpcurf0(x,y,k,w=w,
---> 88                                 xb=bbox[0],xe=bbox[1],s=s)
     89         if data[-1]==1:
     90             # nest too small, setting to maximum bound

error: failed in converting 1st keyword `w' of dfitpack.fpcurf0 to C/Fortran array
```

Comment: We can't reproduce without the LeadersOnly folder, though if you past an exact copy of the traceback you're getting we might be able to figure it out. Also, I made some adjustments to your indentation that the code would run.

Comment: Not sure about the solution - but please change your 0-padding to something a bit nicer!  The lines initializing z could be replaced by `z = '%06d' % x`

Comment: have added in one of the error chains that I get....

I get other ones if I fix this by changing to stampnew = np.linspace(stamp[0],stamp[-1],50) but then get further errors, this time with regards to the pyplot function

Answer (score 4):

Let's analyze your code a bit, starting from the `for x in range(0, 2500, 50):`

- You define `z` as a string of 6 digits padded with 0s. You should really use somestring formatting like `z = "{0:06d}".format(x)` or `z = "%06d" % x` instead of these multiple tests of yours.
- At the end of your loop, `stamp` will have `(2500//50)=50` elements.
- You check for the existence of your file `path`, then open it and read it, but you never close it. A more Pythonic way is to do:

  ```
  try:
      with open(path,"r") as f:
          do...
  except IOError:
      do something else
  ```

  With the `with` syntax, your file is automatically closed.
- `pr1` and `pr2` are likely to be 1D arrays, right? You can really simplify the construction of your `p1` and `p2` lists as:

  ```
  p1 = pr1.tolist()
  p2 = pr2.tolist()
  ```
- Your lists `a1`, `a2` have the same size: you could combine your `for elem in range(len(a..)-1)` loops in a single one. You could also use the `np.diff` function.
- at the end of the `for x in range(...)` loops, `finger` will have 50 elements **minus** the number of missing files. As you're not telling what to do in case of a missing file, your `stamp` and `finger` lists may not have the same number of elements, which will crash your `scipy.UnivariateSpline`. An easy fix would be to update your `stamp` list only if the `path` file is defined (that way, it always has the same number of elements as `finger`).
- Your `stampnew` array has 300 elements, when your `stamp` and `finger` can only have at most 50. That's a second problem, the size of the weight array (`stampnew`) must be the same as the  size of the inputs.
- You're eventually trying to plot `fingernew` vs `stamp`. The problem is that `fingernew` is **not** an array, it's an **instance** of `UnivariateSpline`. You still need to calculate some actual points, for example with `fingernew(stamp)`, then use that in your `plot` function.