# Plotting a smooth curve in matplotlib graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib, netcdf, smoothing

I am reading a netcdf file using python and need to plot a graphs using matplotlib library in python.
The netcdf file is containing 3 variables: `u` `v` and `w` components.
I have to draw these 3 components on a vertical scale. 
Since these data is going to be used in a weather forecasting radar's.
I need to plot these graphs with smooth curves around the corner.
now the plot looks [image: like]
**and the code is...**

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from pylab import *
import numpy  
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import spline


#passing the filename

root_grp=Dataset('C:\\Python27\\MyPrograms\\nnt206rwpuvw.nc')

#getting values of u component
temp1 = root_grp.variables['ucomponent']
data1 = temp1[:]
u=data1[0]

#getting values of v component
temp2 = root_grp.variables['wcomponent']
data2 = temp2[:]
v=data2[0]
#getting values of w component
temp3 = root_grp.variables['wcomponent']
data3 = temp3[:]
w=data3[0]
#creating a new array
array=0.15*numpy.arange(1,55).reshape(1,54)
#aliasing
y=array[0]
#sub-plots
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3, sharey=True)
ax1.plot(u,y,'r')
ax2.plot(v,y,'g')
ax3.plot(w,y,'b')
#texts
ax1.set_title('u component',fontsize=16,color='r')
ax2.set_title('v component',fontsize=16,color='g')
ax3.set_title('w component',fontsize=16,color='b')
show()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot smooth line with PyPlot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283649/plot-smooth-line-with-pyplot)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A simple solution is to do interpolation with splines, as explained in a [nice Scipy tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html).

Here is an example:

[image]