# Matplotlib create a smooth plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scipy

I am using `Python 3.8`, `Matplotlib 3.2.2` and `Scipy 1.5.0`. I am new to Matplotlib and Pandas, but am getting there.
I have some meterological data in a Pandas Dataframe and I can draw a graph of 24hrs of Barometric Pressure and Rain against Time every 5 mins on the x axis.
I would like to smooth the Pressure Curve, but cannot get it to work.
I have looked at the tutorial [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scipy/scipy_interpolate.htm) and also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705062/plotting-a-smooth-curve-in-matplotlib-graphs) amongst others.
Here is the unsmoothed graph:
Plot of Barometric Pressure and Rain against Time:

[image]

and the code:

```
-------- snip --------
ax_graph_pressure.plot(x, y, linewidth=0.5, color='#C00000')
ax_graph_rain.bar(x, z, width=0.002, color='#FF0000')
ax_graph_pressure.grid(which='major', axis='y')
-------- snip --------
plt.show(dpi=96)
```

x is a Datetimeindex array from the df.index of the Pandas Dataframe and y is an array of Floats for Pressure and z in an array of floats for Rain.
I have tried this from the tutorials above:

```
-------- snip --------
unix_time = []
# convert to Unix timestamp
for xx in df.index:
    unix_time.append(xx.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp())
xnew = np.linspace(unix_time[0], unix_time[len(unix_time) - 1], num = 576, endpoint=True)
f2 = interp1d(unix_time, y, kind='cubic')
ax_graph_pressure.plot(xnew, f2(xnew), linewidth=0.5, color='#C00000')
ax_graph_rain.bar(x, z, width=0.002, color='#FF0000')
ax_graph_pressure.grid(which='major', axis='y')
-------- snip --------
plt.show(dpi=96)
```

I had to convert the time in x to UnixTime or I get an error, I also double the number if items to smooth the curve.
When I do this the graph does not appear even after a long wait (more than 10 mins). It gets stuck at the plt.show stage. Normally the graphs appears very quickly.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you probably want a moving average, not an interpolation.

Comment: Alternatively you can look into applying a savgol filter: http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html#scipy.signal.savgol_filter

Comment: You need a smoothing window, in your case a moving average would be OK.  Pandas having a tool for everything, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40060995/2749397) to see how it's simple to add a new column, containing the running average, to your dataframe.

Comment: Thank you @gboffi The more I find out about Pandas the more magical it becomes!
`df['PressureSmoothed'] = df.Pressure.rolling(window=5).mean()`
Produced a nice smooth result. How easy was that!!!!