# How to graph when using the CubicSpline function

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have two arrays, `x` and `y`. I want to create a natural cubic spline for the arrays.

I can't figure out how to exactly plot the graph for the spline.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline

# Calculate 5 natural cubic spline polynomials for 6 points.
# (x,y) = (0,12) (1,14) (2,22) (3,39) (4,58) (5,77)
x = np.array([0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5 ])
y = np.array([12, 14, 22, 39, 58, 77])

# Calculate natural cubic spline polynomials.
cs = CubicSpline(x, y, bc_type='natural')
```

Comment: You likely want to evaluate the spline over some points, somewhat like this:
`
X = np.arange(0,100,100)
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(X, evaluation_of_cs_at(X))
`

Comment: Did you take a look at this post on the forum? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039260/how-to-draw-cubic-spline-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use matplotlib to plot the cubic spline evaluated over the region you're interested in

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.linspace(-1, 7, 100)
Y = cs(X)
plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a set of points at which to evaluate the new function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# x's at which to evaluate.
xs = np.arange(-1, 10, 0.1)

# Plot data with spline.
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.plot(xs, cs(xs))
```

This results in:

[image]