# Smoothing a list with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I have a long list of reward signals (-1 for loss, 0 for tie, and +1 for win). I want to average these signals in "windows" and then smooth this resulting curve to show progress. How do I do this with matplotlib/scipy?

My codes like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = "Qt4Agg"

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = np.array([-1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
)
x = np.array(xrange(len(y)))

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I tried solutions from similar questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283649/plot-smooth-line-with-pyplot), which recommending using a spline, but when applied to my data, that consumes all my memory and crashes my machine.

Answer (score 3):

At some point I found this somewhere.  I am having trouble finding the source, but I use it for convolving 1d ndarrays with various windows, and should solve your problem.

```
def smooth(x,window_len=11,window='hanning'):

    if x.ndim != 1:
        raise ValueError, "smooth only accepts 1 dimension arrays."
    if x.size < window_len:
        raise ValueError, "Input vector needs to be bigger than window size."
    if window_len<3:
        return x
    if not window in ['flat', 'hanning', 'hamming', 'bartlett', 'blackman']:
        raise ValueError, "Window is on of 'flat', 'hanning', 'hamming', 'bartlett', 'blackman'"

    s=numpy.r_[x[window_len-1:0:-1],x,x[-1:-window_len:-1]]

    if window == 'flat': #moving average
        w=numpy.ones(window_len,'d')
    else:
        w=eval('numpy.'+window+'(window_len)')

    y=numpy.convolve(w/w.sum(),s,mode='valid')
    return y
```

So for example, with your data you'd just do:

```
plt.plot(smooth(y))
plt.show()
```

And you get:
[image: smoothed]

Answer (score 1):

The answer you linked recommends using `scipy.interpolate.spline` which constructs the b-spline representation using full matrices. This is why it consumes this much memory. If smoothing splines is what you're after, at the moment you're better off using `scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline`, it should have saner memory footprint.

If you need some window averages/convolutions, check out `numpy.convolve` and/or  convolution/window functionality in [`scipy.signal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/signal.html).