# Smooth line with spline + datetime objects doesn't work

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I have been trying to make a plot smoother like it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283649/plot-smooth-line-with-pyplot), but my Xs are datetime objects that are not compatible with linspace..

I convert the Xs to matplotlib dates:

```
Xnew = matplotlib.dates.date2num(X)
X_smooth = np.linspace(Xnew.min(), Xnew.max(), 10)
Y_smooth = spline(Xnew, Y, X_smooth)
```

But then I get an empty plot, as my Y_smooth is

`[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]`

for some unknown reason.

How can I make this work?

**EDIT**

Here's what I get when I print the variables, I see nothing abnormal :

```
X : [datetime.date(2016, 7, 31), datetime.date(2016, 7, 30), datetime.date(2016, 7, 29)]
X new: [ 736176.  736175.  736174.]
X new max: 736176.0
X new min: 736174.0
XSMOOTH [ 736174.          736174.22222222  736174.44444444  736174.66666667
  736174.88888889  736175.11111111  736175.33333333  736175.55555556
  736175.77777778  736176.        ]
Y [711.74, 730.0, 698.0]
YSMOOTH [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

Comment: I just tried an example, and your approach worked for me. Try to debug each line. What are the values of `Xnew.min()` and `Xnew.max()`? Post more details. What are the values of `X`, `X_smooth`, `Xnew`. For [debugging in a IPython during execution try using `%debug`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/tutorial.html#debugging) to [add breakpoints](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands) or maybe use [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) to view intermediate values during execution.

Comment: I edited the question and added the variables

Comment: From your output I deduce that you're issue is with spline, not the date times. Can you rephrase your question? And maybe try your problem with a smaller set of numbers, like 10 instead of 300, that will display easier in SO and be easier to debug. Also check the `np.splie` docs carefully

Comment: I did the same thing with 10 but no difference.. The docs are small with no examples :

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.spline.html, there's nothing to learn there ;(

Comment: The order of `X` is reversed, `Xnew` decreases but `Xsmooth` increases, reverse `Xnew` and `Y`

Comment: I think you want `interp1d` from scipy. It can do a few spline variants

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `X` values are reversed, `scipy.interpolate.spline` requires the independent variable to be monotonically increasing, and this method is deprecated - use `interp1d` instead (see below).

```
>>> from scipy.interpolate import spline
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = [736176.0, 736175.0, 736174.0]  # <-- your original X is decreasing
>>> Y = [711.74, 730.0, 698.0]
>>> Xsmooth = np.linspace(736174.0, 736176.0, 10)
>>> spline(X, Y, Xsmooth)
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

reverse `X` and `Y` first and it works

```
>>> spline(
...     list(reversed(X)),  # <-- reverse order of X so also
...     list(reversed(Y)),  # <-- reverse order of Y to match
...     Xsmooth
... )
array([  698.        ,   262.18297973,   159.33767533,   293.62017489,
         569.18656683,   890.19293934,  1160.79538066,  1285.149979  ,
        1167.41282274,   711.74      ])
```

Note that many spline interpolation methods require `X` to be monotonically increasing:

- [`UnivariateSpline`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html)

> `x` : *(N,) array_like* - 1-D array of independent input data. Must be increasing.

- [`InterpolatedUnivariateSpline`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html)

> `x` : *(N,) array_like* - Input dimension of data points – must be increasing

The default order of `scipy.interpolate.spline` is cubic. Because there are only 3 data points there are large differences between a cubic spline (`order=3`) and a quadratic spline (`order=2`). The plot below shows the difference between different order splines; note: 100 points were used to *smooth* the fitted curve *more*.

[image: scipy.interpolate.spline]

The documentation for [`scipy.interpolate.spline`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.spline.html)is vague and suggests it may not be supported. For example, it is not listed on the [`scipy.interpolate` main page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) or on the [interploation tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html). The [source for `spline`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.18.0/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py#L2989-L3012) shows that it actually calls [`spleval`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.spleval.html#scipy.interpolate.spleval) and [`splmake`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splmake.html#scipy.interpolate.splmake) which are listed under [Additional Tools](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#additional-tools) as:

> Functions existing for backward compatibility (**should not be used in new code**).

I would follow [cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007)'s suggestion and use [`interp1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d). It is the currently suggested method, it is very well documented with [detailed examples in both the tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#d-interpolation-interp1d) and API, and it allows the independent variable to be unsorted (any order) by default (see `assume_sorted` argument in API).

```
>>> from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
>>> f = interp1d(X, Y, kind='quadratic')
>>> f(Xsmooth)
array([ 711.74      ,  720.14123457,  726.06049383,  729.49777778,
        730.45308642,  728.92641975,  724.91777778,  718.4271605 ,
        709.4545679 ,  698.        ])
```

Also it will raise an error if the data is rank deficient.

```
>>> f = interp1d(X, Y, kind='cubic')
```

> ValueError: x and y arrays must have at least 4 entries

Comment: Does order matter? What if you spline a linear line with a negative slope? X increases as Y decreases...

Comment: I don't know, maybe, I didn't read the docs on `scipy.interpolate.spline` but it doesn't matter, the output of `np.linspace` `Xsmooth` is opposite of the original input, `Xnew`, so that's the issue, it's inconsistent.

Comment: Unexplainable.. When I do what you said:
`newX = list(reversed(matplotlib.dates.date2num(X)))   
         Y = list(reversed(Y))
        X_smooth = np.linspace(min(newX), max(newX), 10)
        Y_smooth = spline(newX, Y, X_smooth)`

I get : `[  755.          1000.68447671  1062.10559586   991.91003112   842.74445597
   667.25554403   518.08996888   447.89440414   509.31552329   755.        ]
`
for this Y:

`[755.0, 755.0, 755.0]`

Comment: I feel like plotting the data might give a better idea of what the question is trying to achieve. Just my opinion...

Comment: The reversing didn't work, but cricket's interp1d worked great, thanks for the help guys

Comment: @Codemon You can make the interpolation smoother by increasing the "steps" in the `linspace`

Comment: It is probably because  of the lack of data, but the cubic and quadratic (worse) is a really bad fit

Comment: @Codemon, spline takes `order` which defaults to 3 or cubic, change it to 2 for quadratic, also `kind` not documented, which I assume determines number of knots, the default is "smoothest"

Comment: Great reference for anyone needing an example to port old sci-py code with splines interpolation. Thanks!