# Spline interpolation with datetime

Tags: python, datetime, tkinter, spline

I am coding an app in Python that collects informations about temperature and timing and plot them in a graph.

As seen here [Smooth line with spline + datetime objects doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38686415/smooth-line-with-spline-datetime-objects-doesnt-work)

I want to interpolate the few temperature values to make smoother the graph temp-time.

This function retrieves the values of temperature and time and puts them into array related to the position (Bedroom and Kitchen):

```
    xTemp, yTemp = dataList[1].split(',')
    xTime, yTime = dataList[3].split(',')

    t = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(xTime)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  # get time string
    st = datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  # get datetime from time string

    x.append(st)
    y.append(xTemp)
    X = np.array(x)
    Y = np.array(y)
    Xnew = matplotlib.dates.date2num(X)

    if(len(X) >= 5):
        X_smooth = np.linspace(Xnew.min(), Xnew.max(), 10)
        Y_smooth = interp1d(X, Y, X_smooth)  
        # , assume_sorted = True, kind = 'quadratic')
        a.plot(X_smooth, Y_smooth)
```

I have got this error:

```
NotImplementedError: [736817.73790509 736817.73791152 736817.73791795 736817.73792438
 736817.73793081 736817.73793724 736817.73794367 736817.7379501
 736817.73795653 736817.73796296] is unsupported: Use fitpack routines for other types.
```

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Which line does throw this error?
I suggest to give an as short as it possible, but runnable code. It seems, that your code is in a loop (Is it?)

Comment: The interpolation with interp1d

Comment: In this case please fetch `X`, `Y`, and `X_smooth` (wiht a debugger or just printing them) and replace the code above, with these values.

Comment: @betonalpfa Yes, my code is in a for loop which retrieves the ip and the port from a json file and perform a request witch CoAP protocol (sockets in practice), in that way I can dinamically update the graph each second or less

Answer (score 1):

Your use of the function [`interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) is wrong. From the docs:

> This class returns a function whose call method uses interpolation to find the value of new points

As you can see from the example on the same page, you should call `interp1d` only with the x and y values you have. This returns a function to which you can pass new x values and which returns the interpolated y values:

```
x = np.arange(0, 10)
y = np.exp(-x/3.0)
f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)

xnew = np.arange(0, 9, 0.1)
ynew = f(xnew)   # use interpolation function returned by `interp1d`
```

So in your case this would be:

```
f = interp1d(X, Y)
X_smooth = np.linspace(Xnew.min(), Xnew.max(), 10)
Y_smooth = f(X_smooth)
```

Comment: Really really thanks to fhdrsdg and @betontalpfa, I finally solved my problem, but I had to use len(Xnew) > 4 to avoid to have ValueError: number of derivatives at boundaries

Comment: I am experimenting another problem, but very rarely:          
interpolation = interp1d(Xnew, Y, kind='quadratic')
ValueError: Expect x to be a 1-D sorted array_like.  I do not know why but it happens very rarely, but the Xnew are dates generated by appending new datetimes that are for sure ordered

Comment: Are you sure there are no duplicate values, because I think that would give the same error. If this isn't the case you should probably ask a new question with all the relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

The `interp1d` returns a function. Try the following:

```
Y_smooth = interp1d(X, Y)
print (Y_smooth(X_smooth[0]))
```

Comment: The result is that I 'can't compare datetime.datetime to float', I should use Xnew instead