# Determine plot smoothing by a parameter

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to create a plot showing both the real data and a smoothed version of the data. Now, I am using the following script:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# DataFrame of 321 values
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
r = df.rolling(window=10, center=True, on='Value').mean()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = df['Value'].plot(style='--', c='b', alpha=0.5)
r.plot(ax=ax, legend=0, c='b')
plt.show()
```

However, I would like this to work similarly to e.g. `TensorBoard`. There, you specify a smoothing parameter between `0` and `1` which changes the window of the rolling mean, `0` being no smoothing and `1` being extreme smoothing. How is this done? Can I also do this in Python?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can use [`scipy.interpolate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#spline-interpolation) package to add smoothness to your data, something like this:

```
from scipy.interpolate import spline

# 300 represents number of points to make between T.min and T.max
# you can use other number to adjust smoothness
axnew = np.linspace(df['Value'].min(), df['Value'].max(), 300)

power_smooth = spline(df['Value'], df['y_Value'], axnew)

plt.plot(xnew, power_smooth)
plt.show()
```

Sample from docs:

Cubic-spline

```
>>> x = np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi + np.pi / 4, 2 * np.pi / 8)
>>> y = np.sin(x)
# s parameter for adjust the smoothness
>>> tck = interpolate.splrep(x, y, s=0)
>>> xnew = np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, np.pi / 50)
>>> ynew = interpolate.splev(xnew, tck, der=0)
```

[image]

Related question: [Plot smooth line with PyPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5284038/213550)

**Update**: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest noticed that `spline` is depreciated in the newest version of `scipy`, so you should investigate the [`splev`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splev.html) and [`splrep`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html). Some samples can be found [here](http://folk.uio.no/inf3330/scripting/doc/python/SciPy/tutorial/old/node21.html).

Comment: @AndreySobolev Another try :)

Comment: This is a nicer one :) I would add that a spline can be prepared with `splrep` method, which actually takes the parameter `s` that controls the smoothness

Comment: Since `spline` is depreciated in the newest version of scipy, using `splrep` and `splev` might be used for future-proof applications.