# How to plot the angle frequency distribution curve in python

Tags: python, distribution, angle, curve

I have only the angle values for a set of data. Now i need to plot a angle distribution curve ie., angle on the x axis v/s no.of times/frequency of angle occurring on the y axis.
These are the angles sorted out for a set of data:-

```
[98.1706427, 99.09896751, 99.10879006, 100.47518838, 101.22770381, 101.70374296,
103.15715294, 104.4653976,105.50441485, 106.82885361, 107.4605319, 108.93228646,
111.22463712, 112.23658018, 113.31223886, 113.4000603, 114.14565594, 114.79809084,
115.15788861, 115.42991416, 115.66216071, 115.69821092, 116.56319054, 117.09232139,
119.30835385, 119.31377834, 125.88278338, 127.80937901, 132.16187185, 132.61262906,
136.6751744, 138.34164387,]
```

How can i do this..??
How can i write a python program for this...?? and plot it in a graph as a distribution curve

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

If you want a line plot as well, it is better to generate the histogram with `numpy` and then use that information also for the line:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

angles = [98.1706427, 99.09896751, 99.10879006, 100.47518838, 101.22770381,
101.70374296, 103.15715294, 104.4653976, 105.50441485, 106.82885361, 
107.4605319, 108.93228646, 111.22463712, 112.23658018, 113.31223886, 
113.4000603, 114.14565594, 114.79809084, 115.15788861, 115.42991416, 
115.66216071, 115.69821092, 116.56319054, 117.09232139, 119.30835385, 
119.31377834, 125.88278338, 127.80937901, 132.16187185, 132.61262906,
136.6751744, 138.34164387, ] 


hist,edges = np.histogram(angles, bins=20)
bin_centers = 0.5*(edges[:-1] + edges[1:])
bin_widths = (edges[1:]-edges[:-1])



plt.bar(bin_centers,hist,width=bin_widths)
plt.plot(bin_centers, hist,'r')
plt.xlabel('angle [$^\circ$]')
plt.ylabel('frequency')
plt.show()
```

this looks like this: 
[image: angle histogram with curve]

If you are not interested in the histogram itself, leave out the line `plt.bar(bin_centers,hist,width=bin_widths)`.

**EDIT2**:

I don't really see the scientific value in a smoothed histogram. If you increase the resolution of the histogram (the `bins` parameter in the `np.histogram` command), it can change quite considerably. For instance, new peaks may occur if you increase the bin count, or two peaks may merge into one if you decrease the bin count. Keeping this in mind, smoothing the histogram curve suggests that you have more data than you do. However, if you really must, you can smooth a curve as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5284038/2454357), i.e.

```
from scipy.interpolate import spline
x = np.linspace(edges[0], edges[-1], 500)
y = spline(bin_centers, hist, x)
```

and then plot `y` over `x`.

Comment: n.p. you can accept the answer, if this solves your problem.

Comment: But my another question is tht this is a histogram plot. How can i plot the curve over this histogram..?? ie i needed in terms of curve (not the gaussian curve) ... and tht would be better if both histogram and curve are in same plot

Comment: Do you mean a line plot with the histogram values?

Comment: Sir , i mean tht a curve plot... but not the Gaussian curve(since it has one maxima), curve plot which follows the histogram (since from histogram thr is more no.of angles around 115 degree and less around 120 degree). so the curve showing peak around 115 degree and minima around 120 degree and so on...

Comment: Can i smoothen  the line plot...?? ie., it shows more pointed one and to the centre of every bar in histogram... but how can i smoothen the line graph since it is depicting the angle distribution (ie to say tht i have more angles around 115 degree, comparatively less round 120 degree ).

Comment: No Sir, i need histogram too, and thn the line graph (smoothened line graph- more or like a free hand curve depicting it)

Comment: Sir, i didn't mean smoothening the histogram, i meant smoothening of the line plot...

Comment: Yes, I know. And I gave you a method how to do that. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Function `hist` actually returns the `x` and `y` coordinates of the bins. You can use this function to prepare the data for the line plot:

```
y, x, _ = plt.hist(angles) # No need for the 3rd return value
xc = (x[:-1] + x[1:]) / 2 # Take centerpoints
# plt.clf()
plt.plot(xc, y)
plt.show() # Etc.
```

You will end up having both the histogram and the line plot. If this is not desirable, clean the canvas before plotting the line by uncommenting the call to `clf()`.

Comment: Can i smoothen the line plot...?? ie., it shows more pointed one and to the centre of every bar in histogram... but how can i smoothen the line graph since it is depicting the angle distribution (ie to say tht i have more angles around 90 degree, comparatively less round 110 degree , again maxima around 120 degree ).

Comment: Sure. You can use `numpy.interp()` on the Xs and Ys https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html