# Smoothing edges of line plot

Tags: python, plot, line, smoothing

So I've tried a whole bunch of spline tools and curve fittings but they all completely change the looks of my plot. I simply want some smmother edges and not sharp corners in the plot.

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

constant = 1.4

xdata = [52.8905, 52.7612, 51.7277, 51.6320, 47.8479]
data1 = [1.4826, 1.5395, 1.5863, 1.5898, 1.5343]
data2 = [1.1551, 1.1570, 1.1690, 1.1700, 1.1707]
ydata = np.zeros(5)

def myfunc(D1, D2, D3):
    polyeff = (np.log(D1) * (D3 - 1)) / (D3 * np.log(D2))
    return polyeff

for i, value in enumerate(xdata):
    ydata[i] = myfunc(data1[i], data2[i], constant)


plt.plot(xdata, ydata)
plt.show()
```

And this is the plot that I want to have smmoth edges on:

[image]

I've tried most of the methods in this: [Smoothing out a curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46633544/smoothing-out-a-curve) but it always ends up looking like somwthing completly different. How can I fix this?

Comment: Which of the particular features that you see when you try the different smoothing methods do you not want? When you say you've tried "most of the methods" is the other post, can you list which ones you have actually tried?

Comment: I think in general, you are going to struggle with a nice smoothing when you have so few points and they are non-uniformly sampled. Non-uniform sampling isn't entirely problematic, e.g., you could use https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/64313/64539, but the small number of samples is. Trying to resample your data with anything other than a linear interpolation is also likely to introduce considerable artifacts.

Comment: I ended up using excel...

Comment: What did it look like with Excel? The two points very close together at the top-left corner - barely distinguishable in your plot - seem to cause all the hassle. Your points are generally too inconsistently spaced to guess what might happen between them.

Answer (score 0):

[image: 'Scatter with smooth lines and markers']

This is the chart type I used in excel, it seems to be specifically made to be used when you have few data points, bingo!

Called 'Scatter with smooth lines and markers'

Comment: Where does the data come from? Your constant looks like the ratio of specific heats for a gas. The whole thing looks like something to do with the efficiency of a thermodynamic cycle.