# Maintain Values for both axis while smoothing with scipy

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have pandas series of type `int`. I am trying to get a smooth curve rather than a zig-zag structure.

[image: Here is the image link]

I saw some previous posta about the same problem but they are smoothing the curve with ( x vs y ) plot whereas in my case I have only a pandas series i.e X axis.

I need a curvy smooth plot.

This is [the post which I am referring to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283649/plot-smooth-line-with-pyplot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `exp` in y-axis. You can simply generate another series of 1,2,... for x-axis.

```
l=[i fo i in range(exp.shape[0])]
series_for_x_axis=pd.Series(l)
```

There you have values for both x and y axis.