# How can I populate a list with points on a curved line?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyautogui, generative

thanks for reading. I'm trying to drag my mouse in a curved line using pyautogui, from what I've read in other threads([Plot smooth line with PyPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283649/plot-smooth-line-with-pyplot)) on here the best way to do so is to establish a series of points and then smooth it out with scipy. I'm trying to find a way to use matplotlib to fill a list with the points of a curve, but I can't find anything about it in their documentation- I can only find ways to plot it using their plotting system.

Thanks for any help you can offer me

Answer (score 0):

figured it out

```
import random

d=(random.randint(1,50))
curve=[]
for i in (0,d):
    a=(random.randint(1,50))
    b=(random.randint(1,50))
    c=(random.randint(1,50))
    x=a*b^c
    curve.append(x)
```

I'm not sure how I'm gonna get this smooth though, any input on that would be helpful, thanks!