# plot data from column with specific value

Tags: python

how can I plot column A as x-axis and B as y-axis with data only related to C.
looking for a graph that looks like density graph.

Comment: `usa = df[df.Country == 'USA']` selects a subset of rows in the dataframe.  To select a subset of columns, such as score & profit,  try: `usa[['score', 'profit']]`.

Comment: Stackoverflow encourages data (such as your table) to be provided as text rather than an image.  This allows responders to more easily post answers using your data.

Comment: got it, I will do that next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having error while extracting specific columns then, it might be because of extra spaces, just try removing extra space. 
Here is code:

```
usa = df[df.Country == 'USA']
usa.columns = usa.columns.to_series().apply(lambda x: x.strip())
usa[['Score', 'Profit']]
```

For Density Graph, the question is still unclear, but here density plot based on what I have understood

```
import seaborn as sns
p=sns.kdeplot(usa['Score'], shade=True, color="r")
p=sns.kdeplot(usa['Profit'], shade=True, color="b")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! for second question, I was wondering if there is any plot that I can choose both x and y axis but still looks similar to the density graph (smooth line, not line graph)

Comment: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283649/plot-smooth-line-with-pyplot) Do have a look at this question, is this what you are looking for